# How to draw line X=1?

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2010

I know how to draw a line with scatter plot options where X is the independent and Y the dependent variable.

In the scatter plot of that data I need to add another line: X=2. I have the following data:

[image]

But how to draw a line X=1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this:

[image: SO21820809 example]

I hear that charting is more different than many other aspects of Excel between versions and that perhaps my version (Excel 2007) is one of the least ‘friendly’ hence some of the reason for “not very easy” but the principle is as @Bill the Lizard has described. In view of some weird behaviour with (my?) Excel 2007 however I recommend being careful about the sequence in which the lines are drawn.

First I suggest getting your chart right for all aspects but the green line. Then add another series with X values of `1` and `1` and Y=2 values of `10` and `-2` (or whatever the limits are of your chosen y-axis as displayed). Select and copy that array (four cells) select your chart and Paste Special…, and Add cells as New Series, Columns, Categories (X Values) in First Column, OK.

This should add a vertical line of the same chart type as the existing (ie XY (Scatter) Scatter with Straight Lines and Markers). The colour can be changed, by selecting that series (click on it and Format Data Series…, Line Color etc) and presumably you would want the markers removed. It was these that for me at first refused to disappear to order – but persistence paid off. Click on either of the data points, and under Marker Options choose none for Marker Type. If necessary, repeat for the other data point – and keep repeating if required!

Also, I selected what was showing as `Series3` (text) in the legend and deleted that.

Forgot to mention that for anything to do with Excel charts **Jon Peltier** is the ultimate authority ([eg](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/AddLineVertSeries.html)) and that an alternative approach is to use an error bar and a secondary vertical axis.

Comment: Yes Thanks!!But how did you draw the green vertical line ?